# Is a distribution function bounded on compact set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $\phi:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be increasing and continuously differentiable with $\phi(0)=0$. Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite space, and $u\in \mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$.

Define $m(t):=\mu\{\phi(u)\ge t\}$. Then $m(t)$ is decreasing, but is it bounded on a compact interval, say, $[1/n, n]$?

Comment: If $m(t)$ is decreasing, its maximum is at the beginning of the interval.

Comment: Are you asking if it's just bounded on a compact interval or bounded on a compact interval of the form $[\frac{1}{n},n]$

Comment: @Gribouillis Yes but isn't the maximum possibly $\infty$?

Comment: @DionelJaime It is decreasing here so I don't think it matters.

Comment: @takecare : You know $m(a)\geq m(t) \geq 0$ forall $t \geq a$.  So I think you are concerned about $m(a)=\infty$.  Just give an example where that holds (for example, let $X=\mathbb{R}$).  Or, explain what $u \in \mathcal{M}^+(\mathcal{A})$ means (I don't know, but it is the only possible assumption which might prevent such examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u$ is the constant function $u(x) = 1$. Then $m(t) = \mu(X)$ when $t \le \phi(1)$ and $m(t) = 0$ when $t>\phi(1)$. If $\mu(X) = +\infty$, it means that $m(t)$ can be infinite.

Comment: What is $A$?  Do you mean $\mu(X)$?

Comment: Why are you defining a function $u$?   I assume $m(t) = \mu(\{u \in X : \phi(u) \geq t\})$, in which case $u$ is just a dummy variable.

Comment: Sorry I meant $\mu(X)$. May be I misunderstood the question. Is there no function $u$ ?

Comment: THere is that mysterious "$u \in M^+(\mathcal{A})$" assumption that I am ignoring since I do not know what it means. I thought the "u" might be a typo "$\mu$" but I still don't know $M^+$.  For the $m$,  it looks like $u$ is a dummy variable that ranges over the set $X$ in the definition of $m(t)$.  Unless I am really misinterpreting.

Comment: I thought $\phi$ was defined on $[0,\infty)$, then what is $X$?

Comment: Oh, maybe you are right.  The counter-example you give would also be possible if $X=[0,\infty)$ though.

Comment: @Michael I understood $u\in M^+$ as meaning that $u$ is a non-negative $A$-measurable function.